Durrett Exercise 4.8.8 (Proving UI of exponential martingale with i.i.d. increment of general distribution)

Let $S_n=\xi_1+\dots+\xi_n$ be a random walk. Suppose $\psi(\theta_0)=E[e^{\theta_0\xi_i}]=1$ for some negative $\theta_0$ and $\xi_i$ is not a constant. In this case, $X_n=\exp(\theta_0 S_n)$ is an exponential martingale. Let $\tau=\inf\{n|S_n\notin (a,b)\}$. Prove that $E[X_\tau]=1$.

The key to this exercise is to show $X_{\tau\wedge n}$ is UI. Many online discussion assumes that $X_{\tau\wedge n}$ is bounded and obtain UI directly. See https://hoillee.wordpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/durrett-5e-solutions.pdf and Application of Optional stopping theorem and exponential martingale (Durret exercise).
However, as no special assumption about $\xi_i$ is made except that its MGF exists for a negative $\theta_0$, it is certainly possible that $\xi_i$ has an unbounded support. Then if the escaping jump $\xi_\tau$ is sufficiently negative, $S_\tau$ could be arbitrarily negative and $X_{\tau}$ needs not to be bounded.
I try to solve this problem without assuming $S_\tau$ is bounded from below. First,
\begin{eqnarray}
E[|S_\tau|]=E[|\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \xi_n1_{\tau\geq n}|]\leq \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} E[|\xi_n|]P(1_{\tau\geq n})=E[|\xi_n|]E[\tau].
\end{eqnarray}
As $\xi_i$ is not constant, one can show that $E[\tau]<+\infty$. Thus, if $E[|\xi_n|]<+\infty$ we could obtain that $E[|S_\tau|]<+\infty$. Here the first difficulty arise, as we only know $E[e^{\theta_0\xi_n}]=1$, we can only conclude that $E[\xi_n^-]<+\infty$ and has no control of the positive part.
If we ignore this for now and assuming $E[|\xi_n|]<+\infty$, then we could bound $S_{\tau\wedge n}$ using $S_\tau^-$. We have
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{X_{\tau\wedge n}\geq K} e^{\theta_0 S_{\tau\wedge n}}dP=\int_{\{X_{\tau\wedge n}\geq K\}\cap\{\tau>n\}} e^{\theta_0 S_n}dP+\int_{\{X_{\tau\wedge n}\geq K\}\cap\{\tau_b\leq n<\tau_a\}} e^{\theta_0 S_{\tau_b}}dP+\int_{\{X_{\tau\wedge n}\geq K\}\cap\{\tau_a\leq n<\tau_b\}} e^{\theta_0 S_{\tau_a}}dP
\end{eqnarray}
Here $\tau_a=\inf\{n|S_n\leq a\}$ and similar for $\tau_b$. In the first term, $S_n\in (a,b)$; in the second term, $S_{\tau_b}\geq b$. In both cases, $X_n\geq K$ for a large $K$ cannot happen. Only the third term left. We can verify that $S_{\tau_a}=-S_\tau^-$. So
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{X_{\tau\wedge n}\geq K} e^{\theta_0 S_{\tau\wedge n}}dP=\int_{\{X_{\tau\wedge n}\geq K\}\cap\{\tau_a\leq n<\tau_b\}} e^{-\theta_0 S_{\tau}^-}dP
\end{eqnarray}
As we know that $E[S_{\tau}^-]<+\infty$, the set over which we integrate shrinks to a null set as $K\to +\infty$. But I still cannot control the integration of $e^{-\theta_0S_\tau^-}$.
I know Durrett's exercises are somewhat casually written. So does he implicitly assume that $\xi_i$ is, say, bounded?
If we don't impose extra assumption, then we only have control over $E[\xi^-]$. Maybe with some clever way we can control $S_{\tau_a}$ and further $X_{\tau\wedge n}$ as well?

I presume that $a<0<b$.
Because $\theta_0<0$, the mean $E(\xi_i)$ exists and is strictly positive, by Jensen. Thus the random walk drifts to the right, so $P(\tau<\infty)=1$. (Indeed, the right tail of $\tau$ decays rapidly, but this won't be needed.)
The stopped process $X_{n\wedge\tau}$ is a martingale, so
$$
1=E(X_{n\wedge \tau})=E(X_n; n<\tau)+E(X_\tau; n\ge\tau).
$$
Now $0<X_n\le e^{\theta_0a}$ on the event $\{n<\tau\}$, so the first term above, $E(X_n; n<\tau)$, tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ because $\lim_n P(n<\tau)=0$. The second term increases with $n$  because $X_\tau>0$. By monotone convergence,
$$
1=\lim_n E(X_{n\wedge\tau}) =E(X_\tau).
$$

Thanks. The application of monotone convergence is smart. Just a small question about your second paragraph. Could we apply Jensen before knowing $E[\xi_i]$ exists? I guess we need to apply Jensen to $\xi^-$ and establish the existence of $E[\xi_i]$ first.

One small correction. The hypothesis $E(e^{\theta_0\xi_i})=1$ implies that $E(\xi_i^-)<\infty$ (because $e^{\theta_0x}\ge 1+\theta_0 x$) and then that $E(\xi_i^-)<E(\xi_i^+)\le+\infty$. (For $b\in\Bbb R$, $b^\pm:=\max(\pm b,0)$.) But $E(\xi_i^+)=+\infty$ is not ruled out. Still, $P(\tau<\infty)=1$ and the rest of the argument remains valid.
